# How to show "transaction response time" graph in LoadRunner Controller?

Tags: loadrunner

In LoadRunner 11.03, after the scenario has finished running (and also while the scenario is running), under 'Available Graphs' → 'Transaction Graphs', there is a graph called 'Trans Response Time':

[image: Loading image..]
<kbd>[maximize image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mtIf7.png)</kbd>

The 'Trans Response Time' Graph should show a graph consisting of `x``y` points whereby `y = the duration of last recorded transaction` and `x = the timestamp of last recorded transaction`.

Let's take the red line for example. Per the numbers below the chart, the maximum recorded duration (`y` axis) is 54 seconds. **However the graph does not show this.** Looking at the graph, we see no points with `y` axis = `54` seconds.

[image: Loading image..]
<kbd>[maximize image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2lHCY.png)</kbd>

The same goes for the other 3 lines on the chart.

Now, when I load the scenario results in LR Analysis. LR Analysis has a section which shows the 'Average Transaction Response Time' graph. This graph consists of `x``y` points whereby `y = the average duration of the last recorded transaction and all transactions before it` and `x = the timestamp of last recorded transaction`:

[image: Loading image..]
<kbd>[maximize image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gD1Og.png)</kbd>

As can be seen, the **shape** of the two graphs are identical. This proves that it's highly likely they are indeed identical, and that the Controller is showing the 'Average Transaction Response Time' graph instead of the 'Transaction Response Time' graph it so claims.

Is this a bug with LoadRunner?

How can we show the  "transaction response time" graph (**not** the "average transaction response time" graph) in LoadRunner Controller?

Answer (score 1):

That is a good question!
**Controller** is showing “average” response time since in online it receives only “**aggregated**” values from all vusers/hosts.
Controller has no details(per vuser)  in “live” mode.
Only after scenario completion, Analysis gather (collate) all the details from all LGs (where they were kept during scenario run) and allow customer analyze them “offline” in Analysis.
**Analysis** will enable you to drill down up to certain single transaction of certain vuser.

Dan Belfer, LoadRunner QA team

Comment: Thanks for the reply Dan. However, since the Controller is able to receive “aggregated” values, doesn't doing that require the Controller to receive the actual values too? For the aggregator needs access to the original raw values to be able to calculate the aggregated value. How can we access these original raw values from the Controller?